# Polymorphism C++: Passing child object by value to function that accepts parent object

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism

I am passing a child object by value to a function that accepts a parent object.
I did not expected to work because I thought that polymorphism involving upcasting applied only for pointers/references.

```
class A
{
public:
  int x;
  A() :x{ 5 } {}
};

class B : public A
{
public:
  int y;

  B() :y{ 5 } { x = 10; }
};

void foo(A a)
{
  cout << a.x << endl;
}

int main()
{
  A a;
  B b;

  // it works to send b to foo
  // foo will print value 10
  foo(b);
}
```

It seems that foo will print value 10 i.e the x value from the child class.
Can somebody help me understand what is happening please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although passing `b` to `foo` will involve [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing), that doesn't affect the value of `b.x` as seen by `foo` since that was set when the object was constructed.  You just sliced away `b.y`, which has no effect in the code as written.